# Past Pushes on AWS parse-server dashboard not showing/connecting

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-server

AWS Elastic-beanstalk Parse-Server 2.2.11 with dashboard 1.0.13.  Everything works fine including test.html page. Apps registering/posting/pulling data from DB and dashboard sending push notes all working.

The only issues is Past Pushes not showing/connecting.  When I click on the link I only get the activity indicator gif.

[image]

How can I debug this ? Where or how do I get to the log files ?

(can there be a conflict with all the old pushs sent prior to migration ? )

(I have pulled the last 100 lines of log off of aws eb instance to no avail)

-Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse is aware of the issue and plans on fixing the problem in the next release of the dashboard.

https://recordnotfound.com/parse-dashboard-ParsePlatform-77430/issues

"Past Pushes infinite loop"